# Print out *accurate* absolute path to files in Python 2 with oswalk + fnmatch

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, operating-system

I've been tasked with finding out a way to search my entire hard drive for any given file using **Python 2** in both Windows and Linux. I was excited to have pieced together various posts to concoct a solution, only to realize the paths being output by Python are not quite correct. Here are my results on Linux:
[image]

Unless the `/home/pi` directory is being queried 3 times from the `for` loops, I shouldn't be seeing the exact `/home/pi/chromium-browser` listed 3 times. I assume a couple of them are directories and one of them is the symlink/executable. However, the filepaths are [incorrectly] all the same.

Here is the same code on Windows:

[image]

Problem is, that is *not* where `OS HW 2.docx` is located. Rather, it's actually located in `C:\Users\Wade\Dropbox\School\Fall 2018\IT344\HW2\OS HW 2.docx`, as seen in the screenshot below:
[image]
There is *not* another instance of `OS HW 2.docx` in the root directory of `C:\Users\Wade`, as Python shell seems to indicate.

Where am I going wrong in my code? Is there a more accurate alternative to `os.path.abspath()`?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `files` list in the tuples returned by `os.walk` contains only the file names without the path names, so you should join it with the path name before you call `os.path.abspath`:

```
print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Beautiful! I had just seen a post suggesting `os.path.join(root, file)` but hadn't quite pieced it together correctly yet. Thanks!